# how to get image in form edit for update using laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

i add type and image of a product, it adds successfully, the image display very well in index, but my problem is edit, when i want to edit a product i click on button edit it retrieve product type but it does not recover the same image I made the code `value = "{{$ file-> image}}"` but not work.

**FileController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
         'type'       => ['bail','required'],
         'image'      => ['bail','mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg','required','max:2048'],
         ]);
        $file = new File(); 
        $file->type = $request->type;
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
       {
        $path = $request->image->store('annonces');
        $file->image = $path;
        }
        $file->save();
        return Redirect::to("file")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
    }
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('file/'.$file->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
          <div class="form-group">
           <label>type <span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
                <select class="form-control" value="{{ $file->type }}" name="type">
                    <option></option> 
                    <option value="1" {{ $file->type == "type1" ? 'selected' : '' }}>type1</option>  
                    <option value="2" {{ $file->type == "type2" ? 'selected' : '' }}>type2</option> 
                    <option value="3" {{ $file->type == "type3" ? 'selected' : '' }}>type3</option> 
                </select>
          </div> 
          
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>image product<span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
              <input type="file" name="image" value="{{ $file->image }}" class="form-control @error('image') is-invalid @enderror">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:10px">update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `new File();` create a new instance of model, not edit the existing instance of model

Comment: @sta thx for u answer ,my question is that I want to see my uploaded product image in form edit first after the update it

Comment: you can have an image tag where you show the current image to the user if you would like ... not sure why you are trying to set the value of the file input

Comment: can you show us the value saved in $file->image ?

Comment: @MarwaneEzzaze thx for u answer ,i add image location link annonces/i4auQNDfMTBSfEwdHiJcZFbgo9A2myIyyU90UVg8.jpeg

Comment: @lagbox thx for u answer because I don't know how to do it

Comment: how to do what?

Comment: @lagbox for example if i want update product type, i get product type in form edit after i change its value, i also want to get upload image value in input file after image change

Comment: you can't set the value of the file input in HTML

Answer (score 0):

First, you make sure this command is executed, this makes a sym link to storage in public

```
php artisan storage:link
```

you'll notice that a public folder was created inside storage/app.
second you need to save the images into the public disk :
for example :

```
$path = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('annonces', $request->file('image'));
```

then on your blade, you can simply do this to show the image :

```
{{ \Storage::disk('public')->url($file->image) }}
```

I dont think it will show on an input, but perhaps you can show the preview of the image in an  tag above the input, so it shows the current avatar of that user